# Questions with easy online answers

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As the Buddhism site is still  in Private beta, Is it acceptable to ask a question which the answer can be found on the internet easily (to build up the base), or is it discouraged?

As an example, answer to the question,

```
According to Buddhism, where are the heaven and hell located?
```

can be found on the internet by a Googling [heaven in buddhism](https://www.google.lk/search?q=heaven%20in%20buddhism&oq=heaven%20in%20buddhism&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2.968j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html
http://www.londonbuddhistvihara.org/qa/qa_hhe.htm#qa_hhe3

Comment: Do you have some specific questions in mind? There's nothing _a priori_ wrong with asking a question whose answer is easily available on the internet, but some questions of that sort are bad for other reasons. For example, a question like "Who was the Buddha?" would not be great because there isn't anything that we could say here that wouldn't be better answered by Wikipedia or any introductory text on Buddhism. On the other hand, a question like "What is jhana?" will also be answered in many places on the internet, but there is a lot more room for getting various perspectives there.

Comment: @senshin Updated the question with example question...

Answer (score 2):

As long as the question is not too broad but focused and fits into the Q&A style of this site,  I don't see a good reason to exclude them. In worst case, we would attract new users to this site when they find a response to that question in google.

Otherwise we would get into trouble if we want to exclude "too easy" or "easy to google" questions - this always depends on the user. Some may not be good with Google (they exist). There are not stupid questions, just stupid answers.

That said: if they fit, I would like to see them.