# The 'beginner' tag

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

There's a [beginner](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag.

Should it exist? Is it being well used?

[Asking fundamental “beginner” questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/254) says that the site shouldn't be 'seeded' artificially with beginner questions; but what about 'beginner' questions which appear naturally, which are asked by beginners?

I suggest that tags are to help people find things. Interested and knowledgeable people could perhaps 'curate' the collection of 'beginner' questions:

- Add the 'beginner' tag to questions that are especially interesting to beginners
- Remove the 'beginner' tag from questions that are not especially interesting to beginners

Perhaps the beginner tag shouldn't exist at all (see [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)) -- although for this subject (i.e. for Buddhism, although not for StackOverflow which deals with software development problems) the beginner tag *is* appropriate, IMHO.

The comments to [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3815/254) suggest that collecting/tagging 'beginner' questions might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am (very) new to the site, but here is my opinion.  I believe the subject matter (existing tag) and summary of each question are adequate to allow the user to filter through what they want to read or don't.  As an analogy, if I went into a bookstore and walked to a section that interested me, I wouldn't normally find a sub-section called "Beginners".  I would browse the titles and pick out what struck me.

For beginner's knowledge I would think that users would do some historical or scriptural study to gain a basic level of knowledge.

Hope offering my opinion helps.  I'm sure others can make a good argument for the Beginner tags.  BTW, I am truly impressed by what I see on the site so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should. I have not used it but some people may like to use it.
If it helps people feel welcome then why not.

Comment: "Why not": because it's difficult to decide how to use it well. Should it be used for every topic? If not, which topics should and shouldn't it be used for? A potential problem is that, if the tag is misleading (by saying "This is a beginner topic; and, other topics which don't have this tag are not beginner topics") then it's harmful, or doing more harm than good.

Comment: Yes. Only for a short time to help people move into the site. It lasts a week on the profile then goes. Non newbie! lol

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! The [tag:beginner] tag is currently one of the 'tags' which is used to tag topics (i.e. to tag questions) ... it's not used to tag user profiles. The tag is visible in the [list of all tags](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags). Each person chooses what tags they use when they create their questions, so the use of tags is haphazard and might be cleaned up sometimes. Currently [13 questions use the beginner tag](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner).

Comment: I already tried to answer that question, [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/7392/254). I don't know what more I could say, to answer that question.

Comment: Sorry mate, I have done the work now and found the right answer if you go back. The most important Precepts are the Ten Precepts. The 227 and 311 are mostly an elaboration and further clarification of the Ten Precepts